# popup javascript Once in each visit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Use this code JavaScript popup work in smartphone

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var shouldOpenWindow = true;
function open_on_click(url,name) {
     if( /Android|iPhone|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      window.open('market://details?id=picture.profile.logo.football','picture profile logo football');
      // if you want that only on first click the popup must be opened, and not on any subsequent clicks, then do this
      shouldOpenWindow = !shouldOpenWindow;

   }
}
</script>
<body onclick="open_on_click()">
```

I want to make the page emerges during each new session
For example, once every hour

Answer (score 0):

*window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date*

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

So just set a variable that will hold the last time the user visited the site, then either show or skip the popup accordingly.

You need to check if your target devices support it though, some older mobile browsers might still have troubles here.

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

**Source** : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp